# PHP MYSQL TWIG Dropdown Menu Creation

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, twig

I'm new to twig, but have a fair understanding of php and mysql.  What I'm trying to do should be simple but I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to simply create a mysql driven dropdown menu using php and twig for the template engine.

I have separate PHP & twig template files and what I can't work out is how it should all fit together.  The PHP currently does all the clever stuff and echos $template->render(array (...etc ) at the bottom of the page.

Please can someone provide an example of how to form a simple dropdown menu using php, mysql and twig rendering in html?

Thank you

edit->
Ok so I have:

```
// get list of years we have data for
$stmt = getvisithistoryyear($db);
$years = $stmt->fetchAll();


echo "<select name=\"pcid\">"; 
echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
foreach ($years as $year){
echo "<option value='".$year['year']."'>".$year['year']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

in my php file which displays the dropdown, but isn't part of my separate twig template.  What I don't know how to do is display it in the twig template, sorry for being vague but I don't know what to do so makes it hard to explain!

the above function just returns a list of years ie 2013, 2012, 2011 and it is these I want to display in a dropdown to allow the user to choose which year they want to select.

in my template I currently have:

```
<table class="flexitable">
{% for y in years %}
<tr>
<td><a href="visitarchive.php?year={{y.year}}">{{y.year|escape}}</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

which displays a long list of years, I just want to format it into a dropdown

to set up the twig template I use:
    // include and register Twig auto-loader
    include '../Twig/Autoloader.php';
    Twig_Autoloader::register();

```
// define template directory location
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../templates');

// initialize Twig environment
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

// load template
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('dashboard/visitarchive.tmpl');
```

to render the twig I call the following from my php at the bottom

```
// set template variables
// render template
echo $template->render(array (
'pageTitle' => 'Visit Archive',
'etc' => 'etc'));
```

Comment: Please [edit] into your question the code you've tried. It is much easier for us if we can see what you've done!

Comment: Have you done any template rendering in your project? Could provide some source about what you've done yet? Otherwise this link may help you how to create different pages using twig template http://devzone.zend.com/1886/creating-web-page-templates-with-php-and-twig-part-1/

Comment: I have done lots of template rendering, but just can't figure out how to format a dropdown menu using php and twig.  I don't know if the <options> part should be in the Php or the twig template or if it's in the php how to render it to the twig template

Comment: Thanks for the source; just one more thing is the way you render your template

Answer (score 4):

I made a few helpful macros for data bound form controls in twig.

You can put these into an html or twig file.

I put them in a file I named "forms_helpers.html" (you'll need to change the comments to html comments if you do that).

```
//accepts options as a simple list or range.
/*
    name: control name
    id: control id
    bound_value: the currently selected value
    opt: a range of values e.g. 1..6

*/

{% macro simpleDropdown(name, id, bound_value, opt) %}
    <select class="form-control" id="{{id}}" name="{{name}}">
        {% for a in opt %}
            <option {% if (a == bound_value) %} selected {% endif %} value="{{a}}">{{a}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endmacro %}

//accepts options as an associative array.
/*
    name: control name
    id: control id
    bound_value: the currently selected value
    options_array: the associative array that provides the options. e.g. a list of inventory items from a database
    text_field: the field name in the collection that will provide the option text
    value_field: the field name in the collection that will provide the option value
*/
{% macro arrayDropDown(name, id, bound_value, options_array, text_field, value_field) %}
   <select class="form-control" id="{{id}}" name="{{name}}">
       <option value="0">[SELECT]</option>
        {% for a in options_array %}
            <option {% if (a[value_field] == bound_value) %} selected {% endif %} value="{{a[value_field]}}">{{a[text_field]}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endmacro %}
```

Here's how to use the macros:

```
{% import "forms_helper.html" as forms %}
<div>
    {{ forms.simpleDropdown("myControlName","myControlId", currentlySelectedValue, 0..10)}}
</div>
```

I have a few others if anyone is interested, but these two should handle most dropdowns.

Comment: This is a most excellent answer and I'd be interested in seeing the other helpers you've created. 
Seems like twig should have a repo for helpers like this, but they don't seem to care too much for non-symfony implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do in your php file which render the page

```
// fetch all data you need before rendering the template
$stmt = getvisithistoryyear($db);
$years = $stmt->fetchAll();

// define template directory location
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../templates');

// initialize Twig environment
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

// load template
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('dashboard/visitarchive.tmpl');

// as you see I pass the $years to template below
echo $template->render(array (
   'pageTitle' => 'Visit Archive',
   'years' => $years
   'etc' => 'etc'
));
```

Now you can change your template as

```
<table class="flexitable">
   <tr>
      <td>Years: </td>
      <td><select name="pcid">
      {% for y in years %}
         <option value="{{ y['year'] }}">{{ y['year'] }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      </select></td>
{% for y in years %}
</table>
```

Hopefully it helps

Comment: @user3670221 base on what you provided on your source I just mixed them to show you the way to create your form using twig

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot, nearly there.  getvisithistoryyear returns an array but the template is displaying an empty dropdown and not showing the year.  My array shows: Array ( [0] => Array ( [year] => 2013 ) [1] => Array ( [year] => 2012 ) [2] => Array ( [year] => 2011 ) [3] => Array ( [year] => 2010 ) [4] => Array ( [year] => 2009 ) [5] => Array ( [year] => 2008 ) [6] => Array ( [year] => 2007 )) What should I put in the <option value="{{ y[''] }}"></option> section?  putting year in the '' doesn't seem to work

Comment: I don't know how come my last changes were not submitted; it should be `<option value="{{ y['year'] }}">{{ y['year'] }}</option>`; I updated my answer; base on the array you provided it should work

Comment: Thank you Javad so much, that worked great.  Really appreciate your time and efforts helping me out.

Comment: @user3670221 you could pick it as solved to help others as well